# Como percorrer uma matriz de 2 dimensões em C e exibir?

Tags: c, array, algoritmo, matriz

Nesse código, tenho uma matriz(array) de duas dimensões, iniciei e quero printar com o printf, mas não sei como:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int matriz1 [3][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    int matriz2 [3][4] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};

    for(i=0; i<12; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", matriz1[i]);

    }

  system("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

Eu tentei com o for i<12, porque é de tamanho 12, mas ele exibe outros números.

Comment: Sua pergunta ficaria mais clara se você mostrasse quais são os "outros números" que você está obtendo como saida.

Comment: Eu estou tentando obter os números declarados na matriz.

Comment: Eu sei o que você está obtendo. É só que, em geral, também ajuda se vc falar qual são os números errados que seu programa está imprimindo.

Comment: Mas agora eu já reescrevi o código, não sei mais.

Comment: Nao se preocupe. Era só uma dica pra sua proxima pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile o seu programa com warnings (opçao `-Wall`) que o compilador vai te dar uma dica do que está errado.

O problema que você tem é que uma matriz de duas dimensões deve ser acessada usando `matriz[i][j]`, onde i e j são os índices da linha e coluna, respectivamente. O que está acontecendo no seu código é que `matriz[i]` é um ponteiro para a i-ésima linha da matriz e o seu printf está fazendo um "cast" desse ponteiro para um número. Você também está tentando acessar linhas da matriz que não existem (o que em C resulta em comportamento não definido)

A maneira mais fácil de percorrer a matriz corretamente é com um par de loops:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Declarar variável em for? Da erro.

Comment: Compiladores modernos pra C aceitam declarar dentro do for. Se vc estiver usando o gcc use `--std=c11`. Se você estiver usando o visual studio, troque de compilador :) Mas pode declarar fora do for se preferir

Comment: Sim, estou usando o gcc e o codeblocks, consegui resolver.